# How to authenticate to Facebook without redirect?

Tags: facebook, rest, redirect, authorization

Could suggest a way to authorize my web application in Facebook to get access_token with no need for redirect? I found out that this in fact is possible with deprecated Facebook REST API, but I cannot register new application to use it.

Regards,
ToM

Answer (score 0):

You can only accomplish this with the facebook javascript library.  With the PHP library, you are stuck with redirecting them to facebook... If they cancel out on facebook, they are now off your site.

With the javascript library, you get a modal window that if they cancel out of, just stay on your page.

Here's a short blurb on how to make the javascript button appear on your page and do a simple login check:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
 <script>
     window.fbAsyncInit = function() {

     // Initialize Facebook Connect
    FB.init({
       appId  : 'YOUR_FACEBOOK_APP_ID_HERE',
       status : false, // Check login status
       cookie : true, // Enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
       xfbml  : true,  // Parse XFBML
       oauth  : true
    });

     };

   // Get Facebook Connect JS and append it to the DOM
   (function() {
   var e = document.createElement('script'); 
    e.async = true;
    e.src = document.location.protocol+'//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1';
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
   }());

  function fbLoginCheck(response){
     if(response.status != 'unknown'){
       //reload or redirect once logged in...
       window.location.reload();
    }
   }
 </script>

   <a class="fb_button fb_button_medium"  
    onclick='FB.login(fbLoginCheck,{ scope: "user_about_me,user_location,user_birthday,email,publish_stream"})'>
   <span class="fb_button_text">Join with Facebook</span></a>
```

Comment: As fair as I know using JS there is still no possibility not to have redirects with Graph API. It was only possible with REST API...

Comment: The example you posted still requires redirect. It is set in App settings on FB.

Comment: @TomaszŚcisło I just do a window.location.reload(); but this could an ajax call to a local php file that uses the facebook php api to get the token and pass it back to the client.

Comment: I get this error: An error occurred with SocialContactSynchro. Please try again later.

API Error Code: 191
API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application
Error Message: Invalid redirect_uri: Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.

Comment: @TomaszŚcisło Odd, never encountered that before.